# String array error or bad declaring

Tags: arrays

```
public class Hotel{
    int lb;
    String nazwa;
    String [] tablicaPok;
    public Hotel (int lbH , String nazwaH){
        nazwa = nazwaH;
        lb = lbH;
        String [] tablicaPok = new String [lb];
    }
    public  String dajNazwe (){
        return nazwa;
    }
    public int ilePokoi (){
        return lb;
    }
    public void TestTab (){  co_w_tablicy
        for(int i=0 ; i < lb ; i++)
            tablicaPok[i] = ("element nr: " + i );
    }
    public void whatsInTab (){
        for(int i =0 ; i < lb ; i++)
            System.out.println ("el. nr : " + i + " ma wartosc " + tablicaPok[i]);
    }
}
```

I created class `Hotel` with the ability to save some String to created in object Hotel array.  When I tested it, it throws a NullPointerException. I'm not sure if I am testing that array badly or if it is declared incorrectly.

Comment: Is this code written in java?

Comment: yes, it is. Maybe used names are misleading ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor, you should use

```
tablicaPok = new String [lb];
```

instead of

```
String [] tablicaPok = new String [lb];
```

so that you are referencing the same variable.

You should also initialize it so that when you call whatsInTab(), it will have something to show for it.  Something like:

```
for(int i=0 ;i < lb ; i++){
    tablicaPok[i] = "";
}
```

Comment: changing constructor was enough Ty.